# Изменение полей и значений json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Всем привет.
Подскажите, как изменить значение в json при переносе его в другой json файл?
Например, есть такая структура:

```
{
    "objects": [
    {
        "type": "indicator",
        "labels": [
            "networkgenius:type=\"ip\"",
            "networkgenius:category=\"Network settings\"",
            "networkgenius:to_export=\"True\""
        ],
        "pattern": "[network-traffic:dst_ref.type = 'ipv4-addr' AND network-traffic:dst_ref.value = '127.127.127.127']"
    }
]
}
```

Нужно, чтобы при переносе в другой json структура была такой:

```
"type":"ip",
"category":"Network settings",
"to_export":True,
"value":"127.127.127.127"
```

Сейчас я нахожу в исходном json файле структуру и переношу ее как есть:

```
    {{
    "labels": [
        "misp:type=\"sha256\"",
        "misp:category=\"Artifacts dropped\"",
        "misp:to_ids=\"True\""
    ],
    "pattern": "[file:hashes.'sha256' = '7bbd9af062e427bb2beb6a6778704707c1cc7145d8f09f2a676e2c55848a4bb7']"
}
```

Код:

```
import json
import re

with open("C:\Programming\Python\Test.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

objects_list= data.get('objects')

new_json = dict()
for c_obj_dict in objects_list:
    if c_obj_dict['type'] == ('indicator'):
         new_json['labels'] = c_obj_dict.get('labels')
         new_json['pattern'] = c_obj_dict.get('pattern')

with open("result.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(new_json, file)
```

И доп.вопрос - если исходных структур много, как записать в новый файл все эти структуры, а не одну?
Спасибо!